# Select limited number of distinct rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I have a table in this format:

```
Name     | Description    | option_id
"Apple"  | "Sweet fruit"  | 3
"Apple"  | "Sour fruit"   | 4
"Pear"   | "Sweet fruit"  | 5
"Orange" | "Orange fruit" | 3
"Carrot" | "Vegetable"    | 3
```

I run the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Description LIKE '%fruit%'` and get this:

```
Name     | Description    | option_id
"Apple"  | "Sweet fruit"  | 3
"Apple"  | "Sour fruit"   | 4
"Pear"   | "Sweet fruit"  | 5
"Orange" | "Orange fruit" | 3
```

I want to get only 2 distinct fruit *Names*, so the result of query should be:

```
Name     | Description    | option_id
"Apple"  | "Sweet fruit"  | 3
"Apple"  | "Sour fruit"   | 4
"Orange" | "Orange fruit" | 3
```

But I obviously don't get 3 records, as using `ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 2` causes query to stop when there are 2 records ready.

I want to produce as many records as possible, as soon as their name is in first 10 of distinct.
Here is what I came up so far:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Name ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 2
) ORDER by option_id ASC
```

Is there a better way of doing it without nesting? Query should be as fast as possible.

**P.S.** To complicate the matters, this is not my full query, but a mere part of it. In full, it looks something like this (without `LIMIT`):

```
SELECT table.*,
    MATCH (Name, Description) AGAINST ('fruit') AS relevance,
    MATCH (Name) AGAINST ('fruit') AS name_relevance
FROM table
WHERE MATCH (Name, Description) AGAINST ('fruit')
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY name_relevance DESC, relevance DESC, Name ASC
```

And I Name is more than just a name, but also some information about it, such as "Fresh Green Apple", "Apple Fruit", etc.

Comment: Why "Orange" and not "Pear"?

Comment: @GoatCO Sorry.. I removed some code before posting. It should make more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way or another, you need to get the list of names that you are accepting. Doing this in a subquery, as you have, is probably the simplest.

You can also use a temporary table which will probably speed this up a bit.

Perhaps Try Comparing these two. I suspect the second will be faster with bigger tables.

Here is one that's essentially the same as yours I believe

```
WITH fruit AS (SELECT TOP 2 DISTINCT Name FROM table1 WHERE Description LIKE '%fruit%' ORDER BY Name ASC)

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT * FROM fruit
) ORDER by option_id ASC
```

This one uses the Temp table

```
Create TABLE #fruit (Name NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #fruit
SELECT TOP 2 DISTINCT Name FROM table1 WHERE Description LIKE '%fruit%' ORDER BY Name ASC

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT * FROM #fruit
) ORDER by option_id ASC
```

**Edit for MySQL**

Here is a TempTable solution for MySQL

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fruit
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1 WHERE Description LIKE '%fruit%' ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 2

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT * FROM fruit
) ORDER by option_id ASC
```

**Edit to use Join**

This *should* preserve the performance gains above, although it might be worth testing.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fruit
SELECT DISTINCT Name, order FROM table1 WHERE Description LIKE '%fruit%' ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 2

SELECT * FROM table t
JOIN fruit f ON t.Name = f.Name
ORDER by f.order
```

Comment: MySQL lacks support for CTE. Therefore `WITH` won't fly.

Comment: Edited to add MySQL solution, because I wasn't paying enough attention the first time.

Comment: Temporary table works great for limits. I get the right number of `fruits`, however I do not get `Names` in the correct order. Table also has a primary key and if I don't use `ORDER BY option_id`, everything is sorted by id. In my temporary table, there is another level of sorting, besides 'Name ASC'..

Comment: You can put multiple columns in the Temporary table to be used for sorting.

Comment: But how do I sort results of the query using `IN()`?

Comment: The query used to create the temp table can be any query so you can sort it however you'd like and add whatever columns you need. You can then join to the temp table instead of doing IN() and you will have the sorting column available to you.

This join will still preserve most of the performance gains assuming the table will be relatively small.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that may prove faster:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table1 a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Name 
      FROM table1
      WHERE Description LIKE '%fruit%'
      ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 2)b
 ON a.Name = b.Name
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61470/7/0)